# How to get only City, State, Country from lat, long in android

Tags: android, google-geocoder, street-address

I have the below code to convert lat, long to human readable address. Now iam getting full details including street name. How can i get only city, state, country? I don't want anything more details.  Please help me.

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
try {
   List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

   String add = "";
   if (addresses.size() > 0) 
   {
      for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
     add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
   }

   showToastMessage(add);
}
catch (IOException e1) {                
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The amount of detail in a reverse geocoded location description may vary, for example one might contain the full street address of the closest building, while another might contain only a city name and postal code. This will return the city name and country name

```
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
    }
```

For details you can look into the [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) object

Comment: Quite interesting is that the locality is often null.
For example I am currently in the Czech capital, Prague.
locality is null and the city is actually in the "sub-admin" part of the geolocation. The address itself is correct.
so if you build international apps you should be very aware that geocoder information and reliability can not really be trusted.

Comment: This was a great find for me. Good point @John, I guess we should use addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea() in that case wrapped in a conditional statement to detect if locality is null. Maybe? I am still new to this myself ;)

Comment: So no state available in Address?

Answer (score 25):

Use the following methods on the objects from addresses:

`getLocality()`

`getCountryName()`

Use

`getAdminArea()` to return state.

I do not know how accurate this is for other countries but for addresses in the USA, this returns the correct state name.

P.S. Sorry for writing a whole separate answer, I am not able to make comments yet.

Comment: getAdminArea() won't work .. it returns null for france

Comment: getAdminArea() is overlooked it seems.  It doesn't help that "state" does not refer to an actual piece of land in programming.

Answer (score 4):

To get City, State and Country use code in following way-

```
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `Address` ([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html))  which is returned from the geocoder. 
This has separate methods like `getLocality()` to return the city org `getCountry()` to return the country name etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following methods on the objects from addresses:

```
 getLocality()
 getCountryName()
```

I am not sure how to get the state though.

Comment: Be careful , in some cast getLocality() might be null and you will get null pointer exception  when getting country name.

Answer (score 1):

Add this list of country code in the your string file.

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes">
        <item>93,AF</item>
        <item>355,AL</item>
        <item>213,DZ</item>
        <item>376,AD</item>
        <item>244,AO</item>
        <item>672,AQ</item>
        <item>54,AR</item>
        <item>374,AM</item>
        <item>297,AW</item>
        <item>61,AU</item>
        <item>43,AT</item>
        <item>994,AZ</item>
        <item>973,BH</item>
        <item>880,BD</item>
        <item>375,BY</item>
        <item>32,BE</item>
        <item>501,BZ</item>
        <item>229,BJ</item>
        <item>975,BT</item>
        <item>591,BO</item>
        <item>387,BA</item>
        <item>267,BW</item>
        <item>55,BR</item>
        <item>673,BN</item>
        <item>359,BG</item>
        <item>226,BF</item>
        <item>95,MM</item>
        <item>257,BI</item>
        <item>855,KH</item>
        <item>237,CM</item>
        <item>1,CA</item>
        <item>238,CV</item>
        <item>236,CF</item>
        <item>235,TD</item>
        <item>56,CL</item>
        <item>86,CN</item>
        <item>61,CX</item>
        <item>61,CC</item>
        <item>57,CO</item>
        <item>269,KM</item>
        <item>242,CG</item>
        <item>243,CD</item>
        <item>682,CK</item>
        <item>506,CR</item>
        <item>385,HR</item>
        <item>53,CU</item>
        <item>357,CY</item>
        <item>420,CZ</item>
        <item>45,DK</item>
        <item>253,DJ</item>
        <item>670,TL</item>
        <item>593,EC</item>
        <item>20,EG</item>
        <item>503,SV</item>
        <item>240,GQ</item>
        <item>291,ER</item>
        <item>372,EE</item>
        <item>251,ET</item>
        <item>500,FK</item>
        <item>298,FO</item>
        <item>679,FJ</item>
        <item>358,FI</item>
        <item>33,FR</item>
        <item>689,PF</item>
        <item>241,GA</item>
        <item>220,GM</item>
        <item>995,GE</item>
        <item>49,DE</item>
        <item>233,GH</item>
        <item>350,GI</item>
        <item>30,GR</item>
        <item>299,GL</item>
        <item>502,GT</item>
        <item>224,GN</item>
        <item>245,GW</item>
        <item>592,GY</item>
        <item>509,HT</item>
        <item>504,HN</item>
        <item>852,HK</item>
        <item>36,HU</item>
        <item>91,IN</item>
        <item>62,ID</item>
        <item>98,IR</item>
        <item>964,IQ</item>
        <item>353,IE</item>
        <item>44,IM</item>
        <item>972,IL</item>
        <item>39,IT</item>
        <item>225,CI</item>
        <item>81,JP</item>
        <item>962,JO</item>
        <item>7,KZ</item>
        <item>254,KE</item>
        <item>686,KI</item>
        <item>965,KW</item>
        <item>996,KG</item>
        <item>856,LA</item>
        <item>371,LV</item>
        <item>961,LB</item>
        <item>266,LS</item>
        <item>231,LR</item>
        <item>218,LY</item>
        <item>423,LI</item>
        <item>370,LT</item>
        <item>352,LU</item>
        <item>853,MO</item>
        <item>389,MK</item>
        <item>261,MG</item>
        <item>265,MW</item>
        <item>60,MY</item>
        <item>960,MV</item>
        <item>223,ML</item>
        <item>356,MT</item>
        <item>692,MH</item>
        <item>222,MR</item>
        <item>230,MU</item>
        <item>262,YT</item>
        <item>52,MX</item>
        <item>691,FM</item>
        <item>373,MD</item>
        <item>377,MC</item>
        <item>976,MN</item>
        <item>382,ME</item>
        <item>212,MA</item>
        <item>258,MZ</item>
        <item>264,NA</item>
        <item>674,NR</item>
        <item>977,NP</item>
        <item>31,NL</item>
        <item>599,AN</item>
        <item>687,NC</item>
        <item>64,NZ</item>
        <item>505,NI</item>
        <item>227,NE</item>
        <item>234,NG</item>
        <item>683,NU</item>
        <item>850,KP</item>
        <item>47,NO</item>
        <item>968,OM</item>
        <item>92,PK</item>
        <item>680,PW</item>
        <item>507,PA</item>
        <item>675,PG</item>
        <item>595,PY</item>
        <item>51,PE</item>
        <item>63,PH</item>
        <item>870,PN</item>
        <item>48,PL</item>
        <item>351,PT</item>
        <item>1,PR</item>
        <item>974,QA</item>
        <item>40,RO</item>
        <item>7,RU</item>
        <item>250,RW</item>
        <item>590,BL</item>
        <item>685,WS</item>
        <item>378,SM</item>
        <item>239,ST</item>
        <item>966,SA</item>
        <item>221,SN</item>
        <item>381,RS</item>
        <item>248,SC</item>
        <item>232,SL</item>
        <item>65,SG</item>
        <item>421,SK</item>
        <item>386,SI</item>
        <item>677,SB</item>
        <item>252,SO</item>
        <item>27,ZA</item>
        <item>82,KR</item>
        <item>34,ES</item>
        <item>94,LK</item>
        <item>290,SH</item>
        <item>508,PM</item>
        <item>249,SD</item>
        <item>597,SR</item>
        <item>268,SZ</item>
        <item>46,SE</item>
        <item>41,CH</item>
        <item>963,SY</item>
        <item>886,TW</item>
        <item>992,TJ</item>
        <item>255,TZ</item>
        <item>66,TH</item>
        <item>228,TG</item>
        <item>690,TK</item>
        <item>676,TO</item>
        <item>216,TN</item>
        <item>90,TR</item>
        <item>993,TM</item>
        <item>688,TV</item>
        <item>971,AE</item>
        <item>256,UG</item>
        <item>44,GB</item>
        <item>380,UA</item>
        <item>598,UY</item>
        <item>1,US</item>
        <item>998,UZ</item>
        <item>678,VU</item>
        <item>39,VA</item>
        <item>58,VE</item>
        <item>84,VN</item>
        <item>681,WF</item>
        <item>967,YE</item>
        <item>260,ZM</item>
        <item>263,ZW</item>
    </string-array>
```

Then after add location change method with below code.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        super.onLocationChanged(location);
        try {
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(), 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                String countryName = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
                LogUtils.LOGE("TAG_DATA", getCountryZipCode(countryName), Const.LOG_VISIBILITY);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getCountryZipCode(String country) {
        String CountryZipCode = "";

        String[] rl = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
        for (String aRl : rl) {
            String[] g = aRl.split(",");
            if (g[1].trim().equals(country)) {
                CountryZipCode = "+" + g[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        return CountryZipCode;
    }
```